cypress: how to mock useTranslation in test?
I want to ask that I have a component EmailSignUpView that use react-intl to translate text content.
import { useTranslation as t } from '@utils/hooks';
<div className={styles.notifyContainer}>
      <div className={styles.notifyTextContainer}>
        <h2
          className={styles.signUpheading}
          data-test-id="email-signup-heading"
        >
          {t('email_stay_in_touch')}
        </h2>
      </div>
</div>


and here's how we implement useTranslation
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const useTranslation = (
  id: string,
  values?: Record<string, string | number>
): string => {
  const { formatMessage } = useIntl();

  return formatMessage({ id }, values);
};

export default useTranslation;

and here's my test
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import EmailSignUpView from '@components/EmailSignUpView/EmailSignUpView';
import MockRouter from '../../cypress/support/utils';
import { enTransMessages } from '../../cypress/support/testData/testData';
import * as hooks from '@utils/hooks';

describe('Email Signup Section tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    // Stub the useTranslation hook
    cy.stub(hooks, 'useTranslation').callsFake(() => ({
      t: (key) => {
        const translations = {
          'email_stay_in_touch': 'The text that I want to test!', // Add other key-value pairs as needed
        };
        return translations[key] || key;
      },
    }));
  });

  it('validate default Heading', () => {
    cy.mount(
      <MockRouter>
        <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={enTransMessages}>
          <EmailSignUpView />
        </IntlProvider>
      </MockRouter>
    );
    cy.getByDataID(selectors.heading)
      .should('have.text', 'The text that I want to test!')
      .and('be.visible');
  });
});


but the result is that the text is not as I expected.
Does anyone know where I may be wrong? Thank you!
Update: Post the log here
Type    Function    Alias(es)   # Calls
stub-1  useTranslation      -
spy-1       push    -
spy-2       replace -
spy-3       reload  -
spy-4       back    -
spy-5       forward -
stub-2      prefetch    2
spy-6       beforePopState  -
spy-7       emit    -
spy-8       off -
spy-9       on  -



You're stubbing t instead of useTranslation - maybe that's the issue?

Looks to me the fault in the component - surely you cannot use the hook in the template? All examples I see use it in javascript - can you explain how it works?

Sorry, since it's confidential code, I can't provide the whole code here.
I think I should study react and cypress more first to see if I can fix this.
Thanks for all your helps!

The stub().callFake() should just provide the same result type as the hook itself (type string according to the real hook).
Instead you are returning an object, perhaps trying to implement an equivalent code to the hook?
Try returning a string, the simplest is this:
cy.stub(hooks, 'useTranslation').callsFake(() => {
  return 'The text that I want to test!';
})

...

cy.getByDataID(selectors.heading)
  .should('have.text', 'The text that I want to test!')

If you want to use multiple translations, using the real hook's parameter, perhaps this - assuming id is the language key:
cy.stub(hooks, 'useTranslation').callsFake((id, values) => {
  const translations = {
    'en': 'The text that I want to test!', 
    'zh': '我想要测试的文本', 
    'es': 'El texto que quiero probar.', 
    'ar': 'النص الذي أريد اختباره'
  };
  return translations[id] || 'not found'
})


It does not work, it still shows the original text.
I update the log in the question.
it seems called the stub but still not change the text

All I can tell you is that is definitely how the stub should work. If you still have no result, it could be the fault is in the component. The code you posted for the component does not look correct, as mentioned in comments, but I assumed you were just abbreviating it. If you post the full component, I will show you a working test.
